# D3.js: Quick mouse interaction causes improper views

Tags: d3.js

Whenever I mouse over my elements really quickly the end result is unpredictable.

Is there a way of layering transitions in D3 that prevents this problem or is it just something you have to deal
with like placing elements farther away?

I also tried using mousemove so that continuously moving on a element will refresh it to the correct state but the elements get bigger as you move(even though it's set to a static number) and there is also a lot of flickering.

Here is all my interactivity. It is a bunch of ellipses arranged in a circle with text labels and paths connecting them to one another. (the bundle layout on D3). On mouseover, only the one you mouseover and the relevant connected nodes and paths are shown. However if I go from ellipse to ellipse really fast the ellipse changes sizes but the paths will be unpredictable. I Have to deliberately mouse OUT of the ellipse and back in from an area without a listener.

```
 nodeGroup.on("mouseenter",function(){

  //hides ALL circles 
  svg.selectAll("ellipse")
     .style("opacity","0");

  //reshow the one you mouse over
  d3.select(this).select("ellipse")
    .style("opacity","1")
    .transition()
    .attr("rx", magnifiedCircle)
    .attr("ry", magnifiedCircle/2);

  //make text bigger
  d3.select(this).select("text")
    //.transition()
    .style("font-size","25");

  //remove all paths (draw relevant ones below)
  d3.selectAll("path")
    .style("opacity",0);

  //name of selected node
  var thisID = (d3.select(this).attr("id"));

  //draw alls path related to selected node
  nodeGroup.selectAll("path")
           .style("opacity", function(d,i){
              if(d[0] == thisID){

                  //draw related circles
                  svg.selectAll("#Circle_" + trimWhitespace(d[1]))
                     .style("opacity", 1);
                  svg.select("#Circle_" + trimWhitespace(d[0]))
                     .style("opacity", 1);

                return 1;
              }
              else 
                return 0;
           });
```

Comment: Are you looking for a way to get the mouseover event triggered as soon as your pointer touches an element?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What are the results that are unpredictable? How would you like it to behave? Can you post the code?

Comment: added details to post

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed it by removing the transitions for mouse exit. I think as a general rule of thumb on exits there should be no transitions so that there is no period of time where a race condition can occur. Then the only problems that can occur are overlapped listeners.

Although I still do not know why mousemove would cause the text to continuously grow or why the flickering occurs.